# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need pass Project Model id as project_id to My Task Model table. this is My TaskController

```
     public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');
     $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));
     $task->project_id = $project->id;


    // This will set the project_id on task and save it
    $project->tasks()->save($task);
}
```

this is My form action route regarding to store task data in projects folder blade file is show.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('tasks.store') }}">
```

this is Task Mode

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;
use App\Auth;
use App\Project;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['task_name', 'body', 'assign','priority','duedate','project_id'];



      public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }


     public function projects()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
     }


    //
}
```

this is Project Model

```
 {
        protected $fillable = ['project_name','project_notes','project_status','color','group'];
        //

        public function tasks(){
             return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }


but I got this error massage here
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'project_id' cannot be null
 how can fix this problem?

Comment: You need to add product_id in your store function to your new task that you are creating. It is null because you're not doing that right now.

Comment: can you do example code here? please

Comment: Read @Raiders answer

Comment: please read My edited TaskController is it correct way?

Answer (score 1):

In your store() function you don't give the task a project_id.

So when you save your task it makes the project_id row null. By default this is not allowed for a row. That's why you get this error.

I think adding this line would work:

```
 $task->project_id = $project->id;
```

You can also make the project_id nullable in your migration. If you do that you allow the project_id to be null. But I don't think that, that is something you want.

Comment: where should I add this line  $task->project_id = $project->id;? @Raiders

Comment: Under: $task = new Task. Project $project (The paramater you give to the store function) is the project you want to assign the task to right?

Comment: added this line  $task->project_id = $project->id; to TaskController store methods. but same error occurred here.....

Comment: That should do the job: is it possible that $project is empty or not assigned. And what happens when you replace: $project->tasks()->save($task); for: $task->save(). Otherwise I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: I found some error in My Migration files that means I did not put primary and forign key as well between My project and Task files is this problem with this mattes

Answer (score 1):

In your migration file you are not mention that project_id is null.
You have to add project_id in this way if you are not

```
$table->string('project_id')->nullable();
```

if you not used like that way then you must have to pass project_id as a valid value like 0 or anything but not null.
See the error. It says that project_id can not be null. so you can not use null value as project_id.

you said in you database that project_id is not null but send null value thats why you have got this error. Hope you understand.

Comment: yes I understand that but I need send project_id it is not to be null. problem is not passing project_id to the Task Model.

Comment: in your store function where did you get $project->id. you just pass a Project $project object as a argument but not any information of you table row. so i think it should be null as your code. Pass direct project_id as a second argument of your store function.

Comment: I found some error in My Migration files that means I did not put primary and forign key as well between My project and Task files is this problem with this mattes

Comment: if not solved your migration issue yet then you can give your migration file here.

Answer (score 0):

Only set `project_id` field to a valid value or zero (If it haven't unique index)